# speeding up cvs pserver over WAN

Tags: proxy, cvs

I have a remote location with 5 developers that are using a CVS (pserver) repository in main office via WAN, but the bandwidth i have is only a couple of hundred kbps so CVS operations are fairly slow.

Is there any way to speed this up? I can rsync over a local copy of the CVS root(s) every couple of minutes, so this can handle the updates, but obviously not the commits. Is there any way to say to CVS to update from one server, but push to another one?

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You could try enabling Gzip compression on your SSH tunnel.  That usually improves speed on things like that.

Comment: we did similar for our SVN repo and it seemed to help our developers located overseas.

Comment: I have this already, and they are still complaining ;)

Comment: Oh arse.  Hmm.. Turn gzip compression up full?  Other than that, i'm not actually sure what you can do to further improve it.. You've got a slow connection.. there's not much you can do to change the speed of the connection..